# Website resource for finding cheap cellphone plans in any country

Tags: online-resources, cellphones, data-plans

There are many country- and region-specific "cheap cell phone plan" questions, but here I'm asking for websites to check no matter what country I'm in to QUICKLY locate a cheap cell phone plan.

Keywords being QUICKLY and CHEAP and UNIVERSAL.

Answer (score 2):

Another user of this site put me onto this:

[Pay as You Go Sim with Data Wiki](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data)

It covers a lot of the pre-pay options for many countries around the world.  It describes itself as:

> This wiki collects information about prepaid mobile phone plans from
>   all over the world. Not just any plans though, they must include
>   decent data rates, perfect for iPhone, iPad and Android smart phone
>   travellers, as well as mifi users.

Comment: And what a good discovery that was.